# Updated images in the public folder are not displaying

Tags: reactjs

I've built a react app using create-react-app.

The nature of the program is to allow them to update images for products.
Images are being stored in the public folder, once a user updates an image it changes the url for the product to the new image.

In development this works. In build mode it does not work.
In the build version it will be unable to locate the new image, even though I can confirm that the new image has been uploaded and the new url is correct.

**Image Folder Structure**

[image]

**The Problem Code**
[image]

It will however work again if I rebuild the app, but my understanding is that you wouldn't have to do this with the public folder?